# How to modify dock bar in XFCE4?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, xfce, dock

I'm setting Arch Linux and I'd like to modify the standard dock bar, which is the file that I should edit?

EDIT: like this
[image]

I don't want to use docky

Comment: First try using the GUI itself to make changes, such as right-click on it and select `Panel -> Panel Preferences...`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: What login manager are you using? And try editing your `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xfce4/<somefile>`

Comment: Without login-manager startxfce4

Comment: The people at http://bbs.archlinux.org will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panel settings are saved here `~/.config/xfce4/panel` but you could also try the xfce4-settings-manager.

And to learn how it works you can just download many nice looking examples from here http://xfce-look.org/ and look into the config files that come with these themes.